# Problem creating Iterable Batch Class

Tags: batch

I am trying to create an Iterable Batch Apex Class that Allows Callouts and is Stateful. When I try to save the class I keep getting an error message that says:

> Save error: Type arguments do not match type parameters for : Iterable<t>

Below is the code I am trying to save:

```
global class SampleIterableBatch implements Database.batchable<Map<String, String>>,
                                            Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {

    global final List<Map<String, String>> updates;

    global SampleIterableBatch(List<Map<String, String>> updates) {
        this.updates = updates;
    }

    global Iterable<Map<String, String>> start(Database.BatchableContext info) {
        return updates;
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<Map<String, String>> scope) {
        // Do Something
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough I don't get the error message if I remove the Database.AllowsCallouts and Database.Stateful. Any ideas why this error message is appearing and how to resolve it?

Note: I am seeing this error when I am saving edits to the class from the Force.com IDE.

Comment: Does it say which line is causing the error?

Comment: @MikeChale yes, it says the line causing the error is line 0

Comment: @MikeChale when I try to edit and save the class from within Salesforce the error message is: "Error: Compile Error: Type arguments do not match type parameters for : Iterable<t> at line -1 column -1".

Comment: Any update from SFDC on if the bug fix is planned? I've been experiencing something similar, and came across this post.

Comment: No I haven't heard anything back from SFDC on if or when a bug fix is planned. The workaround mentioned below has been working for me in the mean time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened a case with Salesforce Support on this issue received the response below. It looks like this is a bug so for now one of the workarounds discussed in the other answers is going to be the best method to get around this issue.

> I was following up your case # 08450637.
>
> I would like to inform you that I have got an update from Tier 3 wherein they have informed that this issue is a known issue which is already under our observation and our R&D team is working on it.
>
> Unfortunately, I will not be able to provide you a date when this issue will cease to exist. For now, we will change the status of the case to "Bug Fix submitted" and you will be notified once the issue is resolved.
>
> We do apologize for the inconvenience caused due to this.

Comment: good to know, at least we weren't going mad :)

Answer (score 4):

I think there might be an issue with the editor, through pure chance I managed to get it to save by doing the following:

Original error:

[image]

Changed the parameter types to one that I knew would work and successfully from a previous project and save:

[image]

Then, change the type parameters back to the original:

[image]

Bizarre proof that it did actually save:

[image]

**EDIT:** This only seems to happen on editing in the Web IDE, i.e. you can save successfully first time but not subsequent times.  Confirmed that the following code *does* work with output in dev console:

```
global class BatchMatching4 implements 
Database.Batchable<Map<String,String>>, 
Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful 
{   
    global Iterable<Map<String,String>> start( Database.BatchableContext BC )
    {
        return new List<Map<String,String>>{ new Map<String,String>{ 'key'=>'value' }};
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<Map<String,String>> scope) {
        System.debug( JSON.serializePretty( scope ));
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Having now had to do something very similar to the original problem, I found that by far the least troublesome way to do this is to use Object as the Type and cast accordingly in your execute method:

```
global class SampleIterableBatch implements Database.batchable<Object>,
                                        Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {

global final List<Map<String, String>> updates;

global SampleIterableBatch(List<Map<String, String>> updates) {
    this.updates = updates;
}

global Iterable<Object> start(Database.BatchableContext info) {
    return updates;
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<Object> scope) {
   for( Object item : scope ) {
      Map<String, String> myMap = (Map<String, String>)item;
   }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {
    // Do Something
}
```

}

Comment: Sounds like you are suggesting that there isn't anything wrong with the code and the issue is with Salesforce validating the code. Is this correct? Sounds like the solution then is to write the whole class without saving and hope that it doesn't need to be edited.

Comment: Yes, I am - as I mention above, the code does actually run/work. If I were you, I would write the main implementation logic in another 'helper' class and then you'll have minimal/boiler plate code in the Batch Apex class anyway.  If you edit the main Batch Apex class in the Web UI you should be able to circumvent the problem by giving the class name a new name each time. Bizarre!

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification as well as the suggestion. I will open a case with Salesforce on this issue as well.

Comment: @sfelf, no problem - would be interested to see where you get to with it from SF - would you mind creating an answer when you get one? Thanks

Comment: Sure thing! I will definitely report back what I learn from SF.

Comment: Also note that unless your want the 'global' access modifier, you no longer need it these days to implement Batch Apex interfaces. Useful if your producing a managed package with this code in.

Comment: Just a note. I have .. implements Database.Batchable<sObject> ... and global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<MyCustomObject__c> myObjects) {...